# Cannot boot ubuntu CD on UEFI new laptop (Toshiba Satellite L850)?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uefi, toshiba-satellite

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on a new Laptop coming with Windows 8.
I have read that only 64 bits are compatible with UEFI, so I tried the 32 bit and now the 64 bit.
I disable the Secure Boot from bios, but still got the message "Check media [fail]".
The CD (actually, physically a DVD) boot ok from other laptops or if I set the boot method to non-uefi (but then Windows doesn't - and that's my office laptop).
Any solution? Is it a bug or I lost some info ?

Thanks,
  Antonello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: it works (boots) with the original Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit iso, it doesn't boot  with the 32 bit nor with the 64bit Ubuntu Secure remix 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting holding f-12 then

1. change your settings in bios(or whatever it is) so that fastboot/quickboot is disabled,
2. disable secureboot
3. and change from uefi to csm(that will require going to setup in boot
   menu and checking out every submenu item to find it)
4. then change your boot order to boot from a cd/dvd
5. then once you are are ready to boot the disk up
6. select cd/dvd boot from the smaller boot menu(the single boot menu)

then you should be good to go.

good luck!

Comment: This just solved my problem with Fedora 20 on a Toshiba Laptop. CSM mode specifically did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Ubuntu Secure Remix x64. It is available here http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-secured/files/ . I'm not entirely sure of the differences between that and the normal flavor, but it installed fine for me using usb.

Comment: Actually it didn't work with the Ubuntu Secure Remix: I firt tried with the 32 bit (failing), then I read about the new boot and the Secure Remix 64 bit.. I have tried that iso as well (failed), and finally I got the original Ubuntu 64bit (that worked). I precise that the Remix 64bit worked (booted) from an old laptop, so it's not a problem of downloading/burning the image.. just it didn't work with the new Toshiba, while the original iso did.